# Getting the normalized check constraint text

Tags: sql-server-2008, constraints, smo

I am writing an SQL Server schema comparison tool and I need to extract out the text expression of both default & check constraints from tables from any database version (2000, 2005, 2008 and the forthcoming 2012 version).

I am using the SQL Server 2000 Northwind database as my source database and SQL Server 2008 as the target database.  When I encounter the `[CK_Birthdate]` check constraint on the `Employees` table it contains the text `([BirthDate] < getdate())`.  When scripted out via T-SQL and then run in SQL Server 2008 R2 it becomes `(([BirthDate]<getdate()))` and the spaces are stripped out.

I have tried stripping out the spaces, which works great, but was after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206514/a-simple-way-to-generate-sql-servers-standard-form-of-an-expression) I was shocked to see that SQL Server changes the expression so it no longer matches the original expression.

I am having a bit of difficulty in getting the **normalized** text from the check/default constraint and I don't really understand why SQL Server performs this normalization rather than just leaving the original text intact?  This normalization process is making it virtually impossible do an exact comparison.

I have tried the following:

- Creating a temporary table with a single sql_variant column, but this causes an exception to be thrown because the column name used in the check constraint expression does not exist in the temporary table.  I could parse the expression to extract the column names and create them dynamically, but this would cause a degradation in performance.
- Updating the check constraint back into the text property and then performing a `Refresh()` to get the text back out.  This doesn't work and just puts the original text back in.

If anyone has any suggestions they will be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

I have decided to take the route described in the first option.

Rather than just having a single column in the temporary table I will:

- parse the check constraint expression using [`Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gertd/archive/2008/08/21/getting%20to-the-crown-jewels.aspx) to extract out the column names from the expression and then dynamically add them to the temporary table.
- add the check constraint to the temporary table and then read the `.Text` property back out to get the normalized text.
- drop the check constraint from the temporary table.

So far this seems to work effectively, albeit with a little trade-off in terms of performance, but I can live with this.

I will see how this turns out in the next few weeks and update this question with an answer so other members can use this information.